# how can i add some complex formula to a column using openpyxl,

Tags: python, data-science, openpyxl

I want to add `"'=IF(O{}<=30,"0-30",IF(O{}<=60,"31-60",IF(O{}<=90,"61-90",IF(O{}<=120,"91-120",IF(O{}>120,"120+")))))'"` this formula to my column. I have done this code

```
for row_num in range(2, maxRow):
    ws['P{}'.format(row_num)] = '=IF(O{}<=30,"0-30",IF(O{}<=60,"31-60",IF(O{}<=90,"61-90",IF(O{}<=120,"91-120",IF(O{}>120,"120+")))))'.format(row_num)
```

but it is giving this error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/AMacharla/Documents/openpyxltest.py", line 17, in 
ws['P{}'.format(row_num)] = '=IF(O{}<=30,"0-30",IF(O{}<=60,"31-60",IF(O{}<=90,"61-90",IF(O{}<=120,"91-120",IF(O{}>120,"120+")))))'.format(row_num)
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple

plse someone can help?

Comment: Could you format the code ? It can be achieved using StackOverflow's graphic editor or using tab.

Comment: The exception tells you that you're using `.format()` incorrectly. Check the Python docs.

Answer (score 0):

There are two directions to handle the task

1. write formula to xlsx with python > run formula with xlsx
2. (recommended) read data, parse data and write result to xlsx with python

---

**Option 1** :

All you need to do is to add parameter to `.format()` for each `{}` in your raw string

```
for row_num in range(2, maxRow):
    raw = '=IF(O{}<=30,"0-30",IF(O{}<=60,"31-60",IF(O{}<=90,"61-90",IF(O{}<=120,"91-120",IF(O{}>120,"120+")))))'
    formatted = raw.format(row_num, row_num, row_num, row_num, row_num)
    ws['P{}'.format(row_num)] = formatted
```

---

**Option 2** :

Instead of using excel functions, you can write an equivalent python function, and directly write the result to each row.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

def findRange(n):
    if n<=30:
        return "0-30"
    if n<=60:
        return "31-60"
    if n<=90:
        return "61-90"
    if n<=120:
        return "91-120"
    return "120+"

for r in range(2, ws.max_row+1):
    # "O" : col=15
    # "P" : col=16
    o_value = int(ws.cell(row=r, column=15).value)
    ws.cell(row=r, column=16).value = findRange(o_value)
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```